# Converting from a crystal ball interface to FPS-style camera?

Tags: opengl, graphics, camera, frame-rate

I currently have a crystal ball interface camera set-up where the camera is always looking at the origin and pressing left,right,up,down simply moves around the object.

I want to change this so that the camera can move around freely around the 3D environment.

I currently have two functions, LEFT and UP that have been implemented as the CB-interface I mentioned.

I want the left and right key to strafe left/right, while up/down to rise and sink the camera. How exactly would I go about changing it?

Also..what would be the proper way to move the camera forward and backward? I was thinking maybe draging the mouse could equate to moving foward/backward?

```
void Transform::left(float degrees, vec3& eye, vec3& up) {
eye = eye*rotate(degrees, up);
}


void Transform::up(float degrees, vec3& eye, vec3& up) {
vec3 ortho_axis = glm::cross(eye, up);
ortho_axis = glm::normalize(ortho_axis);

eye = eye*rotate(degrees, ortho_axis);
up = up*rotate(degrees, ortho_axis);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically throw away the entire code and start over. The camera in your scene behaves like any other object and thus has a position and orientation. (Or one transform matrix.) All you need to do is apply the opposite of the camera transformation.

```
glTransformf(-camera.x, -camera.y, -camera.z);
glRotatef(-camera.angle, camera.axis.x, camera.axis.y, camera.axis.z);
```

You get the idea.

What I do in my code is, since I have quaternions for rotation and converting that into a matrix or axis & angle is expensive, I compute the the forward and up vectors for the camera and feed that into gluLookAt.

```
Vector3f f = transform(camera.orientation, Vector3f(1, 0, 0));
Vector3f u = transform(camera.orientation, Vector3f(0, 0, 1));
Vector3f p = camera.position;
Vector3f c = p + f;
gluLookAt(p.x, p.y, p.z, c.x, c.y, c.z, u.x, u.y. u.z);
```

Comment: So in the code you posted here, the camera you are dot-referencing is an object itself?

Comment: Yea, the general case for a camera is a camera that can freely move in space, like any other object. I would even take it so far that it is part of your scene management structure (e.g. scene graph). To make it FPS you just need to attach it to your player avatar. The rendering setup is the same for any behavior of the camera, be it fly camera, ball camera or whatnot; all you do is move the camera differently in space. I never get it why most tutorials show special case setups...

Answer (score 0):

A common setup for FPS controls is to have movement bound to keys (Strafe Left/Right, Move Forward/Back) and looking around tied to the mouse (x-axis: rotate Left/Right, y-axis: pitch up/down).

HTH